# Why ffmpeg is skipping some images?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, slideshow

I'm trying to create a slideshow with cross-fade effect using `ffmpeg`.

As mentioned, another [SE question](https://superuser.com/questions/1265642/ffmpeg-slideshow-with-crossfade), I'm using the following line for this purpose.

```
ffmpeg -i SEQ_%03d.png -i $AUDIO -vf zoompan=d=$TOTAL_DURATION:fps=1/$FADE_DURATION,framerate=25:interp_start=0:interp_end=255:scene=100 -c:v mpeg4 -shortest -maxrate 5M -q:v 2 "temp_file.mp4"
```

Full script is stored in [Github](https://github.com/niyasc/system-bootstrap/blob/master/video-gen).

This works well. But, it is skipping some of my images. It is skipping the images that I created using *GIMP*. These images are appearing, If i keep it at the beginning of the sequence. But, not at the end.

---

I have created a *MVP* for the same.

The issue can be reproduced with following command.

```
ffmpeg -i %02d.png -vf zoompan=d=4:fps=1,framerate=25 out.mp4
```

Input images are available in [Github](https://github.com/niyasc/system-bootstrap/tree/master/mvp).

---

Please help me to understand why this script is not taking some of my images.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All images in your sequence should have the same resolution and pixel format. In the MVP, 03.png has a different pixel format (`rgba`) compared to the other two (`rgb24`).

Convert all images to the same format, and keep ffmpeg from reinitializing the filtergraph.

`ffmpeg -reinit_filter 0 -i SEQ_%03d.png -i $AUDIO -vf scale,format=rgb24,zoompan=d=$TOTAL_DURATION:fps=1/$FADE_DURATION,framerate=25:interp_start=0:interp_end=255:scene=100 -c:v mpeg4 -shortest -maxrate 5M -q:v 2 "temp_file.mp4"`

Comment: Adding ` -reinit_filter 0` parameter fixed the problem. Thank you so much.